# CKEditor which Plugins included in Full Package

Tags: ckeditor

Anyone know which Plugins are included with CKEditor Full Package?

I was looking through the list of Plugins to see which were worth including but there are 476 in total.  Many of these already seem to have been included and installed with the Full Package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of plugins available in the official CKEditor presets (Basic, Standard, Full) here: http://ckeditor.com/presets

Additionally, you can (and should) create a custom build that would contain just the features you need with [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder). It's not a good practice to download the biggest package there is and then just use a small subset of its features.

Visit the [CKEditor SDK](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/) for a collection of samples with different configurations that showcases different editor features.

Comment: Thanks Anna, exactly what I was looking for.  I had been searching around the CKEditor site for ages but hadn't seen that page.